# How to use ElasticSearch NEST to get object where its list contains some parameter?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an class called Product, which can be available in 1 or more countries (but rarely all of them).

I want to include in my query something that makes the my search/query only return products that is sold in that country.

My best bet would be to have a list in my product object, with CountryIds (Ids of countries that the product is sold in). But I cannot find a query parameter in NEST to find all products whose "CountryIds" list contain the given ID (which I know at runtime).
Basically I would like some help on how to write the contents of this method through elastic search.

```
Product[] GetProductsByCountryId(int countryId);
```

The Product class could look something like this:

```
class Product {
   string productName;
   int[] countryIds;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Russ Cam gave me the right idea, but I just wanted to post my full code result:

```
_client.Search<Product>(s =>
            s.Query(q => q.FunctionScore(fs => fs.Functions(ff =>
                ff.ScriptScore(
                    ss =>
                        ss.Script(script => script.Params(p => PopulateParameterDictionary(p))
                            .Inline(GenerateSearchAlgorithm())
                        )))) 
                    &&+  q.Terms(c => c.Name("country_ids_query")
                         .Field(f => f.CountryIdsWhereAvailable)
                         .Terms(country.Id))));
```

This result includes a scoring with an inline script as well. But the important part of the answer here is the second query "country_ids_query".

This filters away products whose CountryIdsWhereAvailable integer array does not contain "country.Id", and still scores them based on my script.

Answer (score 1):

The [`term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) will return documents that contain a country ID within the `countryIDs`.

If you have multiple country IDs, the [`terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) will return documents that contain at least one of the country IDs in the `countryIDs` field.

Comment: Thank you. I find the documentation quite confusing, but the terms query worked for me.